# Java jit compilation costs a long time

Tags: java, jit

I am using ZGC in Java11 openjdk, when I switch code logic by dynamic config, there is always a request that triggers a long cost (200ms+) after a short time. I search gclog but can not find STW, only JIT compilation log like:

```
[2022-04-11T10:05:20.868+0800][515 ][jit,compilation] 29381       1       com.tt.shortcircuit.PriorityInfo::setCurrentMaxPriority
```

I wonder is it possible that JIT compilation cost so long and why it happens, thanks!

Comment: Well ... it probably happens because of your clever dynamic code tricks.  When you change the code ... it needs to be JIT compiled again.  If you want to investigate what is really going on, there are various JVM options for getting more information on JIT compilation.

Comment: But for your specific question, you haven't provided anywhere like enough information to understand why JIT compilation is taking 200 ms+.

Comment: Gc log second partation [515] is tid, this tid point to a C1/C2 CompilerThread0

Comment: Is `com.tt.shortcircuit.PriorityInfo::setCurrentMaxPriority` one of your dynamicly configured methods?  Maybe it is just ... big and complicated.

Comment: After a long cost, requests like this cost short time (less than 10ms)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.   But sure, after a method has been JIT compiled, it will run a lot faster.  (You are executing native code, not interpretting bytecodes.)

Comment: 'Java JIT compilation' hasn't occurred since 1.3 came out with the HotSpot JVM over twenty years ago. A lot of people think that JIT and HotSpot are the same thing, but they aren't.

Comment: Sorry, I just wonder why my code run slowly once and recovered after I switch dynamic code, I suspect jit compilation because of gc log, but I can't explain why C1/C2 compiler thread's compilation  impact on it.

Comment: Well, I think we have answered what you asked.  Please reread my comments above.  In order to JIT compile you use the C1/C2 compiler / thread.  It takes CPU time to JIT compile a large method, and that time used to compile will affect the time taken to run the method ... because it needs to wait while the method is compiled.  If you are dynamically changing the method, this cycle will get triggered ... each time you generate it ... or whatever.

Comment: So basically, you may be spending more CPU time generating code and JIT compiling it than you are saving by using the dynamically generated code.  If that is the case, then your dynamic code strategy is ill-suited to your use-case; i.e. don't do it.

Comment: AFAIK, HotSpot doesn't provide a way to directly control when your code is JIT compiled.  AFAIK, you cannot schedule when the JIT compilation so as to not slow down requests that use the method being (re-)compiled.

Comment: A multi-thread Java process runs in multi-core linux server, C1/C2 compiler thread shall not affect other threads so much, so you mean that when code need to be jit compiled while running, it will wait until compile finished?

Comment: Where does this log entry say that the processing took 200ms?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it's the first request after the switch that takes 200+ms? (not necessarily the JIT compilation itself)

Comment: I'm not sure jit compilation took 200ms,  but no other clue like STW or I/O,  not first request after switch,  after a few time, about 100 requests.

Comment: What makes you so confident that whatever is the reason for the long execution has to be something that appears in the log?

Answer (score 0):

> when I switch code logic by dynamic config, there is always a request that triggers a long cost (200ms+)

It sounds like your dynamic code logic switch is triggering a deoptimization. This is to be expected, as the code has changed, and any JIT compiled version of that code will have to be thrown away. The code will go back to running in the interpreter, which is slower, until it is recompiled again by C1/C2. This likely explains why there is a request that takes a long time shortly after the switch.

Comment: My code cost less than 10ms normally, is it possible cost 200ms while compiling?

Comment: @YimingXie I don't think the code is slower because of an ongoing compilation, that happens in the background all the time. However, after the deoptimization your code will be running in the interpreter. Combined with the the first request triggering the deoptimization itself, which also takes time to do. These things combined certainly seem like a plausible explanation for the slowdown.

Comment: @YimingXie FWIW, you can look at deoptimization events using JFR or `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+TraceDeoptimization`, that might tell you more about what is happening when you switch the config.